# Trying to read file from s3 with FLINK using the IDE getting Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to read a file from s3 using Flink from IntelliJ and getting the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

This how my code looks like :

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.createTypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.parquet.column.page.PageReadStore
import org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.convert.GroupRecordConverter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile
import org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory

class ParquetSourceFunction extends SourceFunction[String]{
  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit = {
    val inputPath = "s3a://path-to-bucket/"
    val outputPath = "s3a://path-to-output-bucket/"
    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    val readFooter = ParquetFileReader.open(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(inputPath), conf))
    val metadata = readFooter.getFileMetaData
    val schema = metadata.getSchema
    val parquetFileReader = new ParquetFileReader(conf, metadata, new Path(inputPath), readFooter.getRowGroups, schema.getColumns)
    //    val parquetFileReader2 = new ParquetFileReader(new Path(inputPath), ParquetReadOptions)
    var pages: PageReadStore = null

try {
  while ({ pages = parquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup; pages != null }) {
    val rows = pages.getRowCount
    val columnIO = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema)
    val recordReader = columnIO.getRecordReader(pages, new GroupRecordConverter(schema))
    (0L until rows).foreach { _ =>
      val group = recordReader.read()
      val myString = group.getString("field_name", 0)
      ctx.collect(myString)
    }
  }
}
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = ???
}

object Job {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // set up the execution environment
    lazy val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    lazy val stream = env.addSource(new ParquetSourceFunction)
    stream.print()
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

Sbt dependencies :
val flinkVersion = "1.12.1"

```
val flinkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion,// % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion,// % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion, // % "provided")
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-parquet" % flinkVersion)


lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= flinkDependencies,
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.3.0" ,
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop" % "1.11.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-table-planner-blink" % "1.12.1" //% "provided"
  )
```

Comment: Can You add the section with external libraries please ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński added

Comment: Alrready answered by Arvid.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is only supported by adding the respective `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` to your plugin folder as described on the [plugin](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/filesystems/plugins.html) docs. For an IDE local setup, the root that should contain the plugins dir is the working directory by default. You can override it by using the env var `FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR`.

To get the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` into plugin, I'm guessing some sbt glue is necessary (or you do it once manually). In gradle, I'd define a plugin scope and copy the jars in a custom task to the plugin dir.